# Best way to convert a list of images to black & white in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, scikit-image

I have a list of images, I want to resize them and convert them to black and white and then display. Here's the code for resizing it:

```
resized_images = [skimage.transform.resize(image, (200, 600))
            for image in images]
##code for changes to black and white

display_images_and_labels(resized_images, labels)
```

`resized_images` is the list of images. I would really appreciate some help, been stuck on this one.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to convert a color image to grayscale consists in passing the parameter `as_gray=True` to the `imread` function. Alternatively you could use [`rgb2gray`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2gray). Give this code a try:

```py
from skimage import io, transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
fnames = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/itbUo.jpg', 
          'https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIAhP.jpg']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(fnames), ncols=1)
fig.tight_layout()
    
 for i, name in enumerate(fnames):
    img = io.imread(name, as_gray=True)
    resized = transform.resize(img, (200, 600))
    axes[i].imshow(resized, cmap='gray')
    axes[i].set_title(name)
```

[image: results]

---

**EDIT**
Previously, the argument was `as_grey:bool` thanks @George Ivannikov.

Comment: Please see other answer.